# how to find near value?

Tags: c

Iam trying to see if there is a shorter method in being able to find the nearest value in a linear search algorithm if the value you are searching for doesnt exist,without using any searching / sorting built in methods. Thank you.
Here is my current method below,although my attempt seems inefficent.
(iam assuming the array is already sorted)

```
public void LinearSearchNearest(int[] data, int target, string dataname)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataname + ": ");
            int StepsNearest = 0;
            int n = data.Length;

            StepsNearest++;
            // Check for corner cases (check the value is actually within range of the array)
            if (target < data[0])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Closest value : {data[0]}, Position : {1} (value outside of array bounds) ");
                Console.WriteLine($"Num of Steps is : {StepsNearest}");
                return;
            }
            if (target > data[n - 1])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Closest value : {data[n - 1]}, Position : {n} (value outside of array bounds) ");
                Console.WriteLine($"Num of Steps is : {StepsNearest}");
                return;
            }

            int closestVal = 0;
            int position = 0;
            int found = 0;
            int targetCount = 0;

            Console.Write("Value is at positions : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                StepsNearest++;
                if (data[i] == target)
                {
                    targetCount++;
                    found++;
                    Console.Write($"{i + 1}, ");
                }
                else
                {
                    StepsNearest++;

                    // Compare closest value currently to new value to see which one is closer to target
                    long along = data[i];
                    long blong = closestVal;
                    long clong = target;

                    var distanceA = Math.Abs(clong - along);
                    var distanceB = Math.Abs(clong - blong);

                    if (distanceA < distanceB)
                    {
                        closestVal = data[i];
                        position = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check if target value was found or not in the array given
            string result = (found == 0) ? $"Closest value : {closestVal}, Position : {position} " +
                                           $"\nNum of Steps is : {StepsNearest}" : $"\nNum of Steps is : {StepsNearest}";
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

UPDATE CODE

```
public void LinearSearchNearest(int[] data, int target, string dataname)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataname + ": ");
            StepsNearest = 0;

            int closestVal = 0;
            int position = 0;
            int found = 0;
            int minDistance = int.MaxValue;

            Console.Write("Value is at positions : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                StepsNearest++;
                if (data[i] == target)
                {
                    found = 1;
                    Console.Write($"{i + 1}, ");
                }
                else
                {
                    StepsNearest++;

                    // Compare closest value currently to new value to see which one is closer to target
                    int distance = System.Math.Abs(data[i] - target);
                    if (distance < minDistance)
                    {
                        minDistance = distance; 
                        closestVal = data[i];
                        position = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check if target value was found or not in the array given
            string result = (found == 0) ? $"Closest value : {closestVal}, Position : {position} " +
                                           $"\nNum of Steps is : {StepsNearest}" : $"\nNum of Steps is : {StepsNearest}";
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What is your question? What error and or issue are you facing if any?

Comment: It looks like you're assuming the array is sorted, right?

Comment: @RufusL yes correct

Comment: you could just keep track of the difference between the target and the last index searched, and update that while the item is less than the target. Once the current item is greater than the target, compare that difference with the previous difference and return the index of the one with the smaller difference.

Comment: I think O(N) where N is the length of the data array is the best you can get if data is unsorted and has no other exploitable properties. If you need to make this query on the same data more often, sorting the data and performing binary search would give you O(N log N). If you only look for a neater way to write the function, try to isolate your algorithm from the input output code and it will be more readable.

Comment: Why can't you use a built-in search? Is this a homework question? (Not that that's a problem, just if not then it wouldn't make sense to avoid built-in features.)

Comment: `int IndexOfClosestExistingValue( int[] data, int target) { int nearest = 0; int minDistance = System.Int32.MaxValue; for ( int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++ ) { int distance = System.Math.Abs(data[i] - target); if (distance < minDistance) { minDistance = distance; nearest = i; } } return nearest; }`

Comment: @MatthewWatson ye its a practise question iam trying, so i dont wanna use any built in so if you know a good solution would be great

Comment: @BitTickler Actually if you use a binary search the complexity is only `O(log N)` for lookups - I guess you mean the `O(N log N)` for sorting the array, and then `O(log N)` for each subsequent lookup.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes indeed. The sorting would be N log N and the lookup then O(log N). I tried to be brief and so this slipped in. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @BitTickler thank you, so i could leave my normal linear search code, and at the end if not value is found then just run that method,iam i correct in saying that?

Comment: @xanderdaily101 Unless your data array has length 0, you will always find a result. If data.Length == 0, it returns 0, which is like `end()` in c++ ;)

Comment: @BitTickler ok thank alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is assumed to be sorted as you said in the comments, then you could just walk through the array until you find a value that's equal to or larger than the target. If the value is equal, then of course we'd return that index.

If the value is larger, then we compare the difference of this value and the target with the difference of the previous value and the target, and return the index of the value with the smallest difference.

If we never find an equal or larger value, then we return the last index:

```
public int GetIndexOfNearest(int[] data, int target)
{
    if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    if (target <= data[0]) return 0;
    if (target >= data[data.Length - 1]) return data.Length - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        // If we find a match, return that index
        if (data[i] == target) return i;
            
        // If this value is greater than the target then we either
        // return this index or the previous index, depending
        // on which one has the smallest diff with the target
        if (data[i] > target)
        {
            var thisDiff = Math.Abs(data[i] - target);
            var prevDiff = Math.Abs(data[i - 1] - target);

            if (thisDiff < prevDiff) return i;
            else return i - 1;
        }
    }

    // We should never get here, since this is the case where all the items are smaller 
    // than the target, which we checked in the third line, but the compiler requires it
    return data.Length - 1;
}
```

Comment: another thing i should have mentioned is i also need to keep returning the duplicate values

Comment: @xanderdaily101 With that, you do a perfect emulation of a real life customer. Adding a game changer to the specification last minute :)

Comment: haha my bad, i just decided to assume since my method doesnt return the intial value, my fault

Comment: IF the data is sorted (which was also not part of the original question), then you would prefer to do a binary search instead of linear search. Once you found a match, collect all equal values. And it is also possible, there are 2 values unequal to each other but with the same minimal distance.... `data: '(4 6) target: 5`

Comment: i added your implementation into my code and seems to work well!, however when i try to display the position with + 1 (because i want the actual position), it just displays the same position as if i didnt add 1 to it? unless i add 2 it works, not sure why this is happening, i added the update code in my post at the bottom,could you take a look please! thank you

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is `StepsNearest` and why do you increment it twice when you don't find an exact match? Why is `found` an `int` instead of a `bool`? Is it supposed to be counting something? Why do you continue to loop (and increment `StepsNearest`) after you've found a match?

Comment: @xanderdaily101 If you just use my method above to get the index of the closest value, then you know if the value was an exact match and you know what position the value was found in. It's not clear to me what your additional code is trying to do.

Comment: @BitTickler i got rit of the second stepsNearest++; as you're right i dont need to increment it there same for the found i change to bool value thanks, however i keep incrementing the loop as i want to find all duplicate values as well. The issue i was having is when i return the position for the nearest value,even when i do + 1 to the position value it still give me that exact same position it doesnt add the 1 for some reason, (the reason i want to add 1 is because i want the actual position, not position via indexing) hope you can help

Comment: When I run your code with `LinearSearchNearest(new [] {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9}, 5, "foo");`, it correctly says the nearest number is `4` at position `4`. What data are you passing in where you aren't seeing correct results?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all in one iteration. This will either find the first exact match or the nearest element to the search value in an UNORDERED array. If there are multiple elements with the same distance to the search value, it will find the first one.

```
let values = [...]; //your value list
let search = ...;  //your value to search
let index = 0; //index where element is found

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // if the current element is an exact match, set the index to i 
  // and break the loop
  if (values[i] == search) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
  // else if current element is "nearer" to the searchvalue than
  // the previously remembered, remember the current index
  else if (abs(values[i] - search) < abs(values[index] - search)) {
    index = i;
  }
}
```

If you assume, that your array is already sorted you could do it as follows

```
let values = [...]; //your value list
let search = ...;  //your value to search
let index = 0; //index where element is found

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // if the current element is an exact match, set the index to i 
  // and break the loop
  if (values[i] == search) {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
  // while the current value is less then the search value,
  // just remember the index 
  else if (values[i] < search) {
    index = i;
  }
  // if the current value is greater then the search value
  // check whether the previous or the current element is nearer to the search value 
  else if (values[i] > search) {
    index = abs(search - values[i]) < abs(search - values[index]) 
      ? i
      : index;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Shorter**? Maybe. What I have to offer is (hopefully) faster.

Let's summarize what you are looking for:

- IN: Array of int, sorted (ascending order)
- IN: target int value.
- OUT: Array of all indices with values with minimal distance to target.

Given, that the data contains sorted data allows us to pick an algorithm, which performs more quickly than linear search. Linear search (O(N)) would be our only choice were the data in the array not sorted.

But as data *is* sorted, we can do binary search, which has O(log n) runtime.
With the help of binary search, we can find 1 or 2 candidates, which have the minimal distance to target.

Then, it is just a matter of looping towards the left and towards the right as long as there are values with that same minimal distance as our minimal candidate had.

A wall of code says more than 1000 words, right? Here we go:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace nearest
{
    class Program
    {
    static int BinarySearchClosest( int[] data, int target, int left, int right)
    {
        if (right < left)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(right));
        if ((right - left) < 2)
        return left;
        var mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if ( target > data[mid])
        return BinarySearchClosest(data,target, mid, right);
        else
        return BinarySearchClosest(data,target, left, mid);
    }
    
    static int IndexOfClosestExistingValue( int[] data, int target) {
        if (null == data) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        if (0 == data.Length)
        return -1;
        // 1.Do a binary search to get within the same zip code of what 
        // we are looking for.
        var ballpark = BinarySearchClosest(data, target, 0, data.Length);
        // 2. we are close. The real minimum distance is either
        // Math.Abs(data[ballpark]-target) or
        // (Math.Abs(data[ballpark+1]-target) IFF (ballpark+1) < data.Length).
        var minDist = Math.Abs(data[ballpark]-target);
        var imin = ballpark;
        if (((imin+1) < data.Length) && (Math.Abs(data[imin+1]-target) < minDist)) {
        minDist = Math.Abs(data[imin+1]-target);
        imin = imin + 1;
        }
        return imin;
    }
    static int[] IndicesOfClosestExistingValues( int[] data, int target)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        var imin = IndexOfClosestExistingValue(data, target);
        if (imin >= 0) {
        var minDist = Math.Abs(data[imin]-target);
        result.Add(imin);
        // Add equally good matches to the left of imin to the result.
        for (var i = imin - 1;
             i >= 0 && Math.Abs(data[i]-target) == minDist; i--) {
            result.Add(i);
        }
        // Add equally good matches to the right of imin to the result.
        for (var i = imin +1;
             i < data.Length && Math.Abs(data[i]-target) == minDist; i++) {
            result.Add(i);
        }
        
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
    internal struct TestCase {
        internal int[] data;
        internal int target;
        internal int[] expected;
    }
    static string TestCaseToString( TestCase tc) {
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat(
        "TestCase{{ data = {{{0}}}, target = {1}, expected = {{{2}}}}}",
        string.Join(", ", tc.data),
        tc.target,
        string.Join(", ", tc.expected));
        return sb.ToString();
    }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        TestCase[] testCases = 
        { new TestCase{
            data = new int[]{},
            target = 42,
            expected = new int[]{} },   // data.Length == 0
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{1},
              target =  42,
              expected = new int[]{0} }, // data.Length == 1
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{1, 41, 45, 99},
              target = 42,
              expected = new int[]{1} }, // somewhere in the middle
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{100,101,102},
              target = 42,
              expected = new int[]{0} }, // far left
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{1,2,3},
              target = 42,
              expected = new int[]{2} }, // far right
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{1,1,1,1},
              target = 42,
              expected = new int[]{3,2,1,0} }, // multiple matches left
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{100,100,100,100},
              target = 42,
              expected = new int[]{0,1,2,3} }, // multiple matches right
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{41,41,41,41,43,43,43,43},
              target = 42,
              expected = new int[]{3,2,1,0,4,5,6,7} }, // multiple matches both sides
          new TestCase{
              data = new int[]{4,6},
              target = 5,
              expected = new int[]{0,1} } // multiple disjoint matches
        };
        int failCounter = 0;
        int testCaseIndex = 0;
        foreach ( var tc in testCases ) {
        try {
            int[] actual =
            IndicesOfClosestExistingValues(tc.data, tc.target);
            bool verdict = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(actual, tc.expected);
            if (false == verdict)
            failCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine(
            "{1}: {0}, actual = {{{2}}}",
                       TestCaseToString(tc),
                       verdict == true ? "OK" : "FAILED",
                       string.Join(", ", actual));
        }
        catch (FormatException) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: FAULTED", testCaseIndex);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: FAULTED (argument null)", testCaseIndex);
        }
        finally {
            testCaseIndex++;
        }
        }
            Console.WriteLine("Done. ({0} tests failed.)", failCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

I did not use C# in many years and if you want to explore algorithms without a lot of lines of code and typing, I strongly recommend to use a more terse language (unless you really want to learn C#). F# is an attractive alternative as it uses the same run time, has the same default libraries and is much more easy on your fingers.